# imap sent folder setup

Tags: imap, windows-live-mail

I want to setup Windows Live Mail with an IMAP account. The account is hosted with Hostgator if that matters. When I currently set up the account I get an *Inbox* and with what looks like a *Drafts*, *Sent*, and *Trash* folder as child folders of *Inbox*. If I send an email from the Hostgator webmail page, it sends fine and there's a copy of the sent message in the *Sent* folder of the web mail. I can also see the sent message in the *Sent* folder of Live Mail. This is all how I would expect it to work. However, when I send a message from Live Mail, it sends fine but I don't see it in the *Sent* folders of either webmail or Live Mail. What I'd like is to have messages sent from either interface to show up in the *Sent* folder of either interface. Did I set this up right or did I miss something?

Comment: Please do NOT post your questions to multiple sites. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://serverfault.com/questions/194558/the-imap-setup-i-want/194632#194632

> To have Windows Live Mail save 
>   ... copies of sent
>   messages on the IMAP server (rather
>   than on your PC), set the following
>   options:
>
> Check the box marked "Store special
>   folders on IMAP server". (Otherwise,
>   drafts, deleted, and sent messages
>   will be stored on your local hard disk
>   -- which is called "Storage Folders" by Windows Live Mail). Enter Sent for
>   the "Sent Items Path". Enter Drafts
>   for the "Drafts path". Enter Trash for
>   the "Deleted Items path". You can
>   leave the "Junk path" set to whatever
>   folder name you desire.

From http://support.tigertech.net/windows-live-mail-imap

Answer (score 2):

windows live mail simply can not handle imap properly. Only when you are lucky it works fine.

A better solution is use thunderbird. It saves you lots of time, because searching for a windows live mail solution probably without any result.

Another alternative is that you don't use imap, use pop3.