# the IMAP setup I want

Tags: imap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [imap sent folder setup](https://superuser.com/questions/203216/imap-sent-folder-setup)

I want to setup Windows Live Mail with an IMAP account. The account is hosted with Hostgator if that matters. When I currently set up the account I get an *Inbox* and with what looks like a *Drafts*, *Sent*, and *Trash* folder as child folders of *Inbox*. If I send an email from the Hostgator webmail page, it sends fine and there's a copy of the sent message in the *Sent* folder of the web mail. I can also see the sent message in the *Sent* folder of Live Mail. This is all how I would expect it to work. However, when I send a message from Live Mail, it sends fine but I don't see it in the *Sent* folders of either webmail or Live Mail. What I'd like is to have messages sent from either interface to show up in the *Sent* folder of either interface. Did I set this up right or did I miss something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [imap sent folder setup](http://superuser.com/questions/203216/imap-sent-folder-setup) by the same author

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To have Windows Live Mail save 
>   ... copies of sent
>   messages on the IMAP server (rather
>   than on your PC), set the following
>   options:
>
> Check the box marked "Store special
>   folders on IMAP server". (Otherwise,
>   drafts, deleted, and sent messages
>   will be stored on your local hard disk
>   -- which is called "Storage Folders" by Windows Live Mail). Enter Sent for
>   the "Sent Items Path". Enter Drafts
>   for the "Drafts path". Enter Trash for
>   the "Deleted Items path". You can
>   leave the "Junk path" set to whatever
>   folder name you desire.

From http://support.tigertech.net/windows-live-mail-imap

Comment: I found that same website earlier and couldn't get it to work but now it does. I musta fat-fingered something. Thanks.